# Getting the 1st date of the current and previous month in U-SQL

Tags: azure, date, u-sql

How to get in U-SQL:

- the 1st date of the current month
- the 1st date of the previous month?

If I was using SQL I would write the following query (any idea how to write it in U-SQL?):

```html
WHERE MyDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C# expressions for that:

```
DECLARE @startDayThisMonth DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
DECLARE @startDayPreviousMonth DateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month - 1, 1);

@data = 
    SELECT 
        x
     FROM 
        y
    WHERE
        MyDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate;
```

Examples can be found at [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/operators/csharp-functions-and-operators#datetime).